# how to debug android TV app using android studio and android-box?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tv

I need to debug my android app  which is already inserted to the my **ZIDOO_X_9S**  android box.But in my case i can't connect it to my android studio through  the USB port.Because my personal laptop and android box does not connected with the USB port. I used USB male to male cable but it doesn't work. Any help to solve this problem would be highly appreciated!

Thank you !

Comment: You can't connect over WiFi?

Comment: yes , WiFi is not working properly in my android box.

Answer (score 4):

USB male to male cable will not work for the same. You should use wifi to do the same.
Connect your TV and System to same wifi and find the ip address of your tv in network settings and then use adb connect  command in terminal.

Comment: To do above WiFi debugging. Is it need a USB at least once?

Comment: @Prihan For mobile phones its definitely required. I also had the same thought earlier but on my Android TV (Toshiba L5400) its working. So thats why I suggested the above.

Comment: thanks for the your valuable answer. in my case my device need to connect USB at least once.Otherwise i can't do it.

Comment: I can ping my device but when I do the adb tcpip 5555 no device found any thought ?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to Debug android tv using USB male to male cable. Currently, I'm using Mi tv and all you have to do is follow these steps.

1. Enable the **Developer Options**
2. Enable **USB Debugging** under the developer option (In the case of MI tv, enable the **MiTv Adb** option as well)
3. Connect the master end of the USB cable to your computer and the other end to the tv
4. Under developer options, go to **Select USB Configuration**. Click on the option and choose MTP(Media Transfer Protocol)

If you follow the above steps you can see the Tv in the android studio running devices [See the attached image for the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MENKd.png)

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure your laptop and your Android TV are connected to the same network
2. Turn on Developer Options on your Android TV
3. In your Android TV, go to Settings -> **Network & Internet**
4. Click on the connected Wifi Network and get the IP Address
5. Go to your laptop terminal and type `adb connect [ip-address]`
6. Might show `failed to authenticate`. So you have to click Allow on the Android TV prompt
7. `adb -s [ip-address] disconnect` to disconnect

Hope this helps those that look for a step by step guideline.